# Issues opening static files using djnago in BeaverDam

Tags: django

I am trying to use the video annotation tool BeaverDam to annotate a static video offline. 
https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam

I have a video file 0.mp4 in the directory '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/videos'

I then included the STATICFILES_DIRS in the setup file:
https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/blob/master/beaverdam/settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "annotator/static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/videos", )
```

I have not been able to view the static folder in the URL. Tried options like
localhost:5000/annotator/static/
localhost:5000/annotator/static/videos

Any help will be highly appreciated

#

#

1) In the settings file (https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/blob/master/beaverdam/settings.py) I have ‘DEBUG’ set to false

```
# Use different key for production
SECRET_KEY = '8pje5%pxibt2c=&j_c+ly5v@x)$r77%h-x3%jluq-@)4^75)ak'
DEBUG = False
```

2) In the settings file (https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/blob/master/beaverdam/settings.py), I have included STATICFILES_DIRS. This is how I have it setup now:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "annotator/static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/videos', ]
```

3) Modified video.html (https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/blob/master/annotator/templates/video.html) to include the static folder

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% static '0.mp4' %} 
{% endblock content %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app.css"/>
….
```

4) python3 manage.py collectstatic gives me:
1 static file copied to '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static', 90 unmodified.

5 ) http://localhost:5000/static/annotator/0.mp4
gives me ‘The requested URL /static/annotator/0.mp4 was not found on this server.’

Comment: just use `localhost:5000/static/`

Comment: Did not work! I ran 'scripts/serve' and 'python manage.py collectstaticscripts/serve' after modifying the settings.py script. Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STATICFILES_DIRS is paths where django looking for static files. STATIC_ROOT is place from which it serve them. You actually need to collect static for serve it using simple command:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

but keep in mind that you must have rights to read this files.

Comment: That did not work :(    "0 static files copied to '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static', 91 unmodified." What does "To add videos, one must upload the video to a CDN (or use /annotator/static/videos to serve on the same server), then create a Django video object that contains the url (host + filename) to the video file.  Alternatively, use ./manage.py shell, and create annotator.Video objects and call video.save()." mean?

Comment: hmmm... What url did you use in your template to serve files? It must looks something like that: {% static 'file_name_event_without_dir_name' %}. Django must serve files contained in your /home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/videos folder and in static tag you need to use path relative from this dir (for example, if there is file named 'cats.mp4' in this dir you need to write {% static 'cats.mp4' %})

Comment: Sorry about this. But where do I add template Tag. I tried modifying 'https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/blob/master/annotator/templates/video.html' to include: {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% load static %}
    {% static '0.mp4' %}

    {% block head %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app.css"/>

      <script>, but it did not do anything. There are multiple template files for this package 'https://github.com/antingshen/BeaverDam/tree/master/annotator/templates'

Comment: Well, it's question about how django templates works. When you extends any template you can replace any content withing defined in base template block. It means if there is {% block content %}{% endblock %} in base template in your child template you need to type something like: {% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %} {% static '0.mp4 %} ... another stuff ... {% endblock %} If it doesn't work, perhaps problem not in template. You can check it just in your browser, enter full url like localhost:8000/static/0.mp4, it must return your video.

Comment: Made some progress. Now I have ' 1 static file copied to '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static', 90 unmodified.' http://localhost:5000/static/0.mp4 does not give me anything though

Comment: Hmmm... Does this file actually exists in /home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/0.mp4?

Comment: originally it is  in '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/videos'. It is copied to '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static/' when I run 1 static file copied to '/home/arl/BeaverDam/annotator/static', 90 unmodified.

Comment: And localhost:5000/static/videos/0.mp4 returns 404 code too?

Comment: I have edited the original post to show all the steps and error (‘The requested URL /static/annotator/0.mp4 was not found on this server.’)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185984/discussion-between-priya-narayanan-and-andellys).